# Angular route paramMap is resolved synchronously the first time

Tags: angular, router

First, let me explain what I'm trying to achieve.

All of this example is reproduced in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DrShacGwBo4U145b81hX?p=preview)

I have an application loader that can be shown using a service. This loader is displayed in my top bar, which is part of my global layout.

I want to show the loader when fetching data. For example, I have a route with some parameter

```
const routes = [
  {path: 'test/:id', component: TestPageComponent}
]
```

When navigating to `/test/2`, the component is created and uses an async service to load some data about the item `2`.

Before actually loading the data, it tells the `LoaderService` to show the loader.

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    // Add or remove .delay(0) to make it work or not.

    this.item$ = this.route.paramMap/*.delay(0)*/.switchMap((params) => {
      this.loaderService.isShown$.next(true)
      this.id = params.get('id')

      // Start with undefined, so the component is cleared before loading the new item
      return this.fakeService
          .load(this.id)
          .do(() => this.loaderService.isShown$.next(false))
          .startWith(undefined)
    })
}
```

Problem is

```
Expression has changed after it was checked
```

This is because the `route.paramMap` observable is resolved synchronously the first time the component is created.

The problem can be easily avoided by using the RxJS operator `delay(0)` to force asynchronous behavior. But it doesn't feel the right way to do it...

You can play with [the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DrShacGwBo4U145b81hX?p=preview), just click on `go to X` to show the `TestComponent`. The first time, it triggers the error, then, when navigating to an other item, the component is not destroyed, so the `paramMap` is asynchronous, and does not trigger the error. You can click on `reset` to go back to home and destroy the `TestComponent`.

I didn't find any issue on the [Angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues) about this, but maybe I'm just bad at searching issues :/

Comment: I created an issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20081